How to deal with multiplication of multiplicities of compound groups in parentheses?
I'm working on a C program that analyzes chemical formulas and counts the total number of elements. The identifyCompound function I've developed can correctly identify individual elements, but I'm having difficulty handling the multiplicities of groups within parentheses.
For example, when processing the formula Fe2(SO4)3, the current output is Fe2S + O4 with a total of 17 elements, but the expected result would be Fe2 + S3 + O12 while still maintaining the correct total of 17 elements.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// Function to identify and count elements in a compound
int identifyCompound(char *input, int *index) {
    int numElements = 0;
    int multiplier = 0;
    int i = *index;

    while (input[i] != '\0') {
        if (isupper(input[i])) {
            // Found an element symbol
            if (numElements > 0) {
                printf(" + "); // Add '+' sign between elements
            }
            printf("%c", input[i]);
            numElements++;

            // Check if the next character is a lowercase letter (indicates more atoms of this element)
            if (islower(input[i + 1])) {
                printf("%c", input[i + 1]);
                i++; // Move to the next character (lowercase)
            }

            // Check if the next character is a digit (indicates the quantity of atoms of this element)
            if (isdigit(input[i + 1])) {
                multiplier = 0;
                while (isdigit(input[i + 1])) {
                    multiplier = multiplier * 10 + (input[i + 1] - '0');
                    i++; // Move to the next digit
                }
                printf("%d", multiplier);
                numElements += (multiplier - 1); // Add the number of additional atoms of this element
            }
        } else if (input[i] == '(') {
            // Start of a group within parentheses
            i++; // Move to the next character after '('
            numElements += identifyCompound(input, &i); // Recursive call to process the group
        } else if (input[i] == ')') {
            // End of a group within parentheses
            i++; // Move to the next character after ')'

            // Check if the next character is a digit (indicates multiplication of the group)
            if (isdigit(input[i])) {
                multiplier = 0;
                while (isdigit(input[i])) {
                    multiplier = multiplier * 10 + (input[i] - '0');
                    i++; // Move to the next digit
                }
                numElements *= multiplier; // Multiply the number of elements by the multiplier
            }
        }

        i++; // Move to the next character
    }

    *index = i; // Update the index to reflect the current position in the input
    return numElements;
}

int main() {
    char input[100];

    do {
        printf("Enter an element or compound (Press 'esc' to exit):\n");
        fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);

        // Remove the newline character (if present) from the input
        input[strcspn(input, "\n")] = '\0';

        if (strcmp(input, "esc") == 0) {
            break; // Exit the loop if the user entered 'esc'
        }

        int index = 0;
        int totalElements = identifyCompound(input, &index);

        printf("\nTotal elements in the compound: %d\n", totalElements);

    } while (1); // Infinite loop until the user decides to exit

    return 0;
}

How can I modify the identifyCompound function to correctly handle the multiplication of group multiplicities within parentheses? For example, when processing the formula Fe2(SO4)3, how can I ensure that the output includes Fe2 + S3 + O12 instead of Fe2S + O4, while still accurately counting the total number of elements?
Thank you in advance for any help or suggestions!

OT: Why do you create your own character classification functions, when you include <ctype.h> that have all of them already covered (in a portable way, in the unlikely event your code is built on a non-ASCII system).

As for your problem, I immediately think of the input as a language and it shouldn't be too hard to create a simple Flex + Bison solution to handle it.

Aside: Press "esc" is not the same as Type "esc".

Can you have nested brackets eg Na(H2(S04)3)3?

Good question @SmellyCat , in the new code I managed to obtain Na + H6 + S12 for Na(H2(SO4)3)3. I will review the code.

Looking at the bit of code, the main thing that struck me was that you're trying to do everything in identifyCompound. This makes it impossible to write test cases for the individual parts of your solution.
As the comments note, the first part of your problem is parsing the input. The second is to then interpret that parsed input, and count the atoms. Think about the interface between the first and the second part - how would you represent the parsed result? You don't want to deal with individual characters anymore. 'Fe' is iron, not two characters.
